# if IP address exist in URL return something else return something

Tags: regex, string, matlab, text-processing, string-parsing

How do I check whether the IP address exist in URL by using Matlab? Is there any function that can be used to check the IP address?

```
data =['http://95.154.196.187/broser/6716804bc5a91f707a34479012dad47c/',
       'http://95.154.196.187/broser/',
       'http://paypal.com.cgi-bin-websc5.b4d80a13c0a2116480.ee0r-cmd-login-submit-dispatch-']

def IP_exist(data):
for b in data:
    containsdigit = any(a.isdigit() for a in b)
    if containsdigit:
        print("1")
    else:
        print("0")
```

Comment: No, I want to check whether the URL consists of IP address, like data 1 & data 2 got the IP then will return 1, while data 3 will return 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `regexp`, you can either use `'tokens'` or look-aheads and look-behinds with regular matching.  Here's the look-ahead/behind approach:

```
>> str = {'http://95.154.196.187/broser/6716804bc5a91f707a34479012dad47c/',
       'http://95.154.196.187/broser/',
       'http://paypal.com.cgi-bin-websc5.b4d80a13c0a2116480.ee0r-cmd-login-submit-dispatch-'};
>> IPs = regexp(str,'(?<=//)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?=/)','match')
IPs = 
    {1x1 cell}
    {1x1 cell}
    {}
>> IPs{1}
ans = 
'95.154.196.187'
>> hasIP = ~cellfun(@isempty,IPs).'
hasIP =
     1     1     0
```

The `'tokens'` approach has a simpler pattern, but the output is more complicated as it has nested cells:

```
>> IPs = regexp(str,'//(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/','tokens')
IPs = 
    {1x1 cell}
    {1x1 cell}
    {}
>> IPs{1}
ans = 
    {1x1 cell}
>> IPs{1}{1}
ans = 
    '95.154.196.187'
```

The same `hasIP` computation works, however.

Comment: How do I write in the Matlab editor instead of command windows?
Because I have a lots of data.....thx

Comment: You mean how do you format your data into an appropriate cell array like `str`?

Comment: I can see my datas at workspace/ variable editor there, but I have to write my code in Matlab editor because I have a lot of feature to check, while "IP address" is only one of those features. I have to save all this in separate file to proceed for the next stage.

Comment: All the above is valid MATLAB code that can be put in a .m file. Is the data a cell array containing strings (check with `whos` and looking at the first element (`tmp=data{1}; whos tmp`)? Regarding different features, each feature would have a very different pattern.

Comment: yes, I get it, thx =D
ya, different features would have their different pattern...I will try out for the next feature.

Comment: hi @chappjc, any ideas with the URLs 'http://890217b8992cb1a6a2.html-html-html-html-html-html-html-html-html-html-html-html.eu/ceas/eu.html?logon=myposte&890217b8992cb1a6a2' & 'http://597e114d2.html-html-html-html-html-html-html-html-html-html-html-html.eu/ceas/eu.html?logon=myposte&597e114d2'? It still return me -1 although it is not the IP address, the IPs = [890217b8992cb1a6a2 597e114d2]. '//(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})/'--> suppose is in the IP format right?

Comment: but using "IPs =regexp(domain_URL,'//(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/','tokens')", return me the wrong answer, I get the correct results when you provide me the previously time. I have thousands of data, should I use this 'IPs = vertcat(IPs{:});', but i cant get the correct results oso, any ideas?

Comment: @user3340270 I don't see an incorrect result. There are no IPs in the two URLs you gave. Both URLs are given with hostnames ending in the .eu top-level domain, not IP addresses.