# check IP address by using function

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I can run this in cmd window, but facing problem when write it in function.

checkIP.m

```
function feature1 = checkIP(data)

%data = importdata('DATA/URL/testing_URL')

domain_URL = regexp(data,'\w*://[^/]*','match','once');
IPs = regexp(domain_URL,'(?<=//)(?<=//)(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})','match','once');

feature1_data = (~cellfun(@isempty,IPs))
feature1(feature1_data~=0)=1;
feature1(feature1_data==0)=-1
end
```

all.m

```
data = 'http://123.456.789.123/stackoverflow.com/questions/23245757/create-and-call-function';
feature1 = checkIP(data)
```

Comment: Your return variable `feature1` is not assigned in the function. If there are no other errors, you should have received an error indicating exactly this problem. Did you mean to use `feature1` instead of `feature1_data`?

Comment: i haven edited as above, any ideas how to fix it? i do need to solve it urgently, thx~

Comment: I think you have a typo in the `cellfun` line (see answer), but also see my updated regexp in [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22075017/2778484). The dot should be a literal dot rather than a regexp symbol for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run `cellfun` the input obviously has to be a `cell`. The problem is that if `data` is a `char` array rather than a `cell` array of `char` arrays, `regexp` will not return a cell, at least not when called with the `'once'` option.  The easiest solution is simply to ensure that the input to the first `regexp` call is a cell array, if only one with a single cell.

Anyway, right before the first `regexp`, add:

```
if ischar(data),
    data = cellstr(data);
end
```

---

Also note that the second `regexp` should escape the dot (`.`):

```
IPs = regexp(domain_URL,'(?<=//)(?<=//)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})','match','once');
```

And out of curiosity, why the repeated look-behind (`(?<=//)`)?

Comment: yes, typo...but i have correct to it, it also show me the error, can i use cellfun in the function? May you correct to me with the code above, because I urgently need it in the function form, many thanks =D

Comment: @user3340270 You didn't post the error message, but I figured it out. See update to answer.